# get the ip address of users opening my website

Tags: php, ip

I want to track the IP address of the users who are opening my website. I have done lot of googling and even other questions asked on stackoverflow but couldn't find the solution. I actually want to know how to I get the IP address by using

```
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] or $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] variables.
```

Comment: use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: You just keep $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] into a variable like $ipaddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; and if you want to save with user information into database then you can save $ipaddress value, if you want to see then use echo $ipaddress.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']!="") 
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} 
elseif ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']!="") 
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
else 
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your client is connected through proxy server then `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` just returns the IP address of the proxy server not of the client' machine. This is the closest you can get to client' ip.

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in your question:
`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will contain the IP of the user accessing your site. Just use it like you'd use any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

For this the answer is simple. just use PHP's $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] to get the IP of the user who accesses a given page/url